# Archive (.tar.gz) Corruption

Tags: linux, data-recovery, tar, archiving, gzip

I've got a .tar.gz archive that has definitely suffered some kind of corruption. The data inside the archive is obviously very precious to me and I'd really like to get my hands on as much as possible. Obviously I don't expect to get all of it, but as much as possible would help.

This archive was sent to me over FTP, but was also corrupted on the end of the person who sent the archive. This should not have been damaged during the FTP transfer. I am unable to get another copy of it.

I've already attempted to do something about this, obviously. I've used an open-source application called [gzrecover](https://github.com/arenn/gzrt) on the original archive then attempted to extract the "recovered" archive produced by gzrecover. However, this didn't avail me very far. I was able to get some of the files out of it, but not all of them. I viewed the archive in Ark (KDE's Archive Manager) and it is able to generate a full listing of the contents of the archive (so, all of the files and folders in the archive), so I have a little hope that the archive still has some kind of chance for recovery.

The original archive is about 18GB in size. The "recovered" archive is around 30GB in size.

I also used GNU cpio to extract from the recovered archive. It begins by successfully extracting some of the contents of the archive (for about two minutes), then begins spamming

```
cpio: Malformed number ��������
```

After running for quite a few days (and spamming my terminal for just as long), I finally get the message

```
cpio: premature end of file
```

As well, during the time of spamming "Malformed number", I do not have any kind of filesize increase from the folder it is extracting to. In other words, no data is recovered at all beyond that.

I've used the two following cpio commands to extract the archive:

```
cpio -ivd -H tar < archive.tar.recovered
cpio -F archive.tar.recovered -i -v
```

Needless to say, I have attempted to recover this archive multiple times with gzrecover as well as extracting each of them with both of these cpio commands.

I'm asking out of being entirely desperate to recover this data. What other methods can I use? How can I recover the data from this archive? The data in this archive means quite a bit to me and I would be distraught to lose it. I'll pretty much do anything to recover it.

Thank you.

Comment: @LMFAO_A_JOKE I wish I could. However, the source files are long since gone. The data is tens of thousands of files, varying in size. Multiple people have this archive and even the original sender has the archive, but it is corrupted on their end as well.

This is literally my only way of obtaining these files.

Comment: Am I missing the obvious ? your are using cpio to recover a `tar.gz` ? what about `tar xvzf` ?

Comment: @Archemar I've always used cpio to extract from broken gzrecovered tar archives. Extracting it via `tar xvzf` fails miserably.

Comment: @Archemar The [provided hyperlink to gzrecover](https://github.com/arenn/gzrt)  suggests using cpio

Comment: To check if it is the same file of the source (and avoid to waste time) you can calculate the MD5 checksum, `md5sum myfile.tar.gz`,  for both files. To try to fix an eventual and wrong Ascii transfer by ftp, you can follow [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18915270/3569208). To solve any eventual doubt about the compression format with `file myfile.tar.gz` you can check if it is really gzip compressed...

Comment: @Hastur Although I don't think it's what you meant, comparing the corrupted versus the gzrecovered archive return two completely different hashes. This makes sense, obviously, considering one of the archives is 10GB or so larger than the other. As for the answer provided, it's returning "binary symbol 0x1F found at line 1; skipping binary file archive.tar.gz. Checking the filetype via file returns "gzip compressed data, was "archive.tar", from Unix, last modified: date".

Comment: Since you said _"this __should__ not has been damaged during the FTP transfer."_ I proposed to do (if still possible) the md5check on your copy and on the original one, in order to avoid to work on a double damaged file... and to start with the less damaged one (I should be more clear :) ). Nonetheless the original copy can be damaged itself by an ftp transfer without the binary mode set, and for this I posted that link. If you have space, time you can try to do `dos2unix -n old.tgz new.tgz -c 7bit`, or `-c ASCII` or ISO or mac...  then `gzrecover` or `gunzip`. In case update the question.

Comment: @Hastur Haha, I feel silly now. It was pretty early for me whenever I replied to that. :) I checked with him (the sender) and his hash matched mine as well as someone else who received the archive. I'll update that.

As well, I did try dos2unix (as stated in the comment above). Regardless of what I input with the original archive, it returns "binary symbol 0x1F found at line 1; skipping binary file archive.tar.gz".

Comment: I suppose it was late night for me... For binary file you have to use `-f` option too. Try all different conversion types. It's a desperate attempt I know... but maybe... [ `-f, --force  Force conversion of binary files.`].  Give it a look [here too](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/dos2unix.htm). BTW do not lose the will to smile over a problem: it is said that it enough to get rid of the problem itself :-)

Comment: You can try http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec and see what it can carve out of the gz...

Answer (score 1):

A "gz" file is a compressed archive of a single file. A "tar" file is a collection of files wrapped up to appear to be a single file. Based on your description, you may be able to extract part of the tar file, but only up to the first error. You'll end up with a partial tar file. The tar contents could then be extracted, but since you only have the first bit, you'll only be able to extract whatever files got placed there.

[This page describes all that in greater detail along with what you can do about it.](http://www.gzip.org/recover.txt) The important bit is: `gunzip < damaged.tar.gz | tar xvf -`

Answer (score 0):

A Windows product that claims the ability to repair .tar.gz archives
is [Archive Recovery](http://www.sysinfotools.com/recovery/archive-recovery.php).

This is a commercial product ($59), but a demo version is [available here](https://www.sysinfotools.com/demo-version/SysInfoTools-Archive-Repair.exe)
that contains all functionalities except saving.

Be minded that this could run for a long time and that success is not guaranteed.

Comment: I'll definitely try this. I don't have access to a Windows machine presently but I'll be picking one up in a couple of days. Thank-you. :)

Comment: It might work using [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/).

Comment: For optimal performance, it'd probably be best to get a Windows machine. I'll be taking an extra home from work so I should be able to do it tonight anyway. If I have any luck, I'll be sure to let you know. :)

Comment: You can always setup a [Virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/), install there a [trial version of windows](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-windows-8-1-enterprise), on this the program and finally you can test it. Note that you can share a part of the guesting (Linux) file system to the hosted one (windows)...

Comment: @Hastur Fair point. I want to be able to shut this computer at night though, so I marked this off as a no-go. I've got it running right now on another machine, but progress is pretty slow.